# Stop part of page being index by search engines?

Tags: search-engine

How can I stop search engines indexing part of my page? Is there an HTML5 element for this?

Its just a line of text that I want to hide (a co-worker doesnt want their name on google for some reason). Im thinking that I could inject the text with javascript, but I have heard google does sometimes look inside javascript files.

I also thought of using images instead of text, but im concerned how this will look cross device and platform. Ive noted text rendering can differ on mac and pc and thats before ive had to think about mobile devices, retina displays, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hide content unless you use the methods you've already outlined above. Your best bet is to use JavaScript in an external file and then block that file using robots.txt.