# Stop part of a HTML page being indexed for search

Tags: html, search, indexing

I manage an Intranet and we have ads cross-selling topics and pages but these are also being indexed.

E.g. we have 1 page on ice cream but an ad which cross sells this page on 150 pages so we have 151 pages indexed for ice cream.

I would like to stop the ad being indexed in search, is there any code/way to do this?

I know the question was already asked but this was 2012 [Stop part of page being index by search engines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410603/stop-part-of-page-being-index-by-search-engines)

Living in hope,

Rodney

Comment: Hi, if this were a website it would probably be OK but as it is an Intranet, having the wrong pages indexed is causing user issues.

Answer (score 0):

Exclusions depend on the particular search engine.

Some support a  or  tag, which seems obvious once you encounter this problem.

Another approach is to get the system to publish a version without the common text, index that, and change the URLs to point at the real version.  Public sites shouldn't do this, the web search engines want to see what end-users will see.

Another approach is to set the search engine to interact with the publishing system or CMS to index the content directly, avoiding HTML entirely.